# grid view scrolling issue?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gridview

I making a gridview that is made of a text and under it an image and everything is working fine but the problem is that when I scroll, the images gets repeated, so any tips on how I could solve this problem

here is my adapter:

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String[] mobileValues;

public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.heartless_gridview_design, null);

        // set value into textview
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.heartless_name);
        textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

        // set image based on selected text
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.heartless_image);

        String mobile = mobileValues[position];


        if (mobile.equals("Shadow")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.shadow);
        } else if (mobile.equals("Soldier")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.soldier);
        } else if (mobile.equals("Large Body")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.large_body);
        } else if (mobile.equals("Silver Rock")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.silver_rock);
        } else if (mobile.equals("Emerald Blues")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.emerald_blues);
        } else {
        }

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mobileValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

please if you know how to fix this please tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so far I understood you should use viewholder pattern and
every time when getView method calls check if viewholder is null initialize it otherwise do nothing just return view..

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder

and good example here - http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-listview-optimizations